# Unclear why this coin change algorithm works

Tags: algorithm

I worked with someone yesterday from SO on getting my coin changing algorithm to work.

It seems to me that,

1. first, `makeChange1()` calls `getChange1()` with the change amount...
2. `getChange1()` checks if amount == 0, if so, it will print the list
3. if `amount >= current denomination`, it will add that denomination to the list then recur, decrementing the amount by the current denomination...
4. if `amount < current denomination`, it recurs on to the next denomination... (index + 1)

I don't understand how `getChange()` will be called again once the amount equals 0... doesn't it just say that if amount == 0, it will just print out the list?

```
    if (amount == 0) {
        System.out.print(total + ", ");
    }
```

Therefore, because of this I'm not sure how the rest of the permutations will be completed... **A picture would reallly help!**

**Input**:

```
12 cents
```

**Output**:

```
[10, 1, 1], [5, 5, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Code**:

```
public void makeChange1(int amount) {
    getChange1(amount, new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0);
}

public void getChange1(int amount, List<Integer> total, int index) {
    int[] denominations = {25, 10, 5, 1};

    if (amount == 0) {
        System.out.print(total + ", ");
    }
    if (amount >= denominations[index]) {
        total.add(denominations[index]);
        getChange1(amount-denominations[index], total, index);
        total.remove(total.size()-1);
    }
    if (index + 1 < denominations.length)   {
        getChange1(amount, total, index+1);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to the world of recursive algorithms

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Yeah, I've been in this world for a few months now... I made a recursive Palindrome checker which makes perfect sense to me... but this does not.

Comment: that's why this world is so much fun. recursive party all night long (no chicks allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an `else-if` and the method doesn't return after printing out the list.

Once it prints out the line, it will continue to

```
if (index + 1 < denominations.length)   {
    getChange1(amount, total, index+1);
}
```

Which will call your function again with an incremented index.

Comment: I realize that it will continue on to that line, but isn't the amount at that point equal to zero? Therefore when you call the last if, `getChange1(amount, total, index+1);` you're passing in zero if you've actually printed out the list already, right?

Comment: Like I completely understand how the first permutation comes out `[10, 1, 1]`, but why would the algorithm be called again to give us `[5, 5, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], etc`...?

Comment: @Growler `amount` is never reassigned, so it will still have the same value at that point that it had at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @Growler Remember that after it prints a permutation you are going to to back up the call stack where amount is not 0.  Then you go try a different permutation.  And this keeps going until you've tried them all.

Comment: @Becuzz ah okay I got hung up on the decrementing amount. So 12 cents keeps getting passed back to the call, with the only change being that the index (denominations) is increased, meaning you're looking at one less coin. Gotcha. I tend to get lost in recursive logic sometimes :/

Comment: @Growler, sepp2k and Becuzz are correct. Here is a simple jsFiddle example that you can step through. Forgive the alerts http://jsfiddle.net/LTkdX/